# Setting max z-index of Google Adsense's auto ads

Tags: html, adsense

I'm displaying auto ads from Google Adsense.
Problem is with z-index. When I open my modals like search modal it is below Google Ads.

[image]

It has     `z-index: 2147483647 !important;`. Mine is 1050.
Can I somehow set z-index of those floating ads? How to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried setting a `z-index` higher than 2147483647 on your modal?

Comment: I know that this will work, but I have to change it in a several places and don't know how google is calculating its own z-index. Maybe it has to do something with my own code.

Comment: This is a bug with side floating ads - they should cover only empty space on a page. What's your website?

Comment: https://www.polskieszlaki.pl

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this issue in several client websites. Google ads are covering navigation menus or modal dialogs. The number 2147483647 is actually the largest integer value in CSS and so you CANNOT use a higher number!

I'm not sure if Google is directly responsible, or if advertisers are exploiting some CSS input, but its a horrible thing for accessibility. I came up with the following code to fix it:

```
function fixRidiculousZindex(){
  var d=document.getElementsByTagName('*'),i,e;
  for (i=0; i<d.length; ++i) {
    e=d[i];
    const s=getComputedStyle(e);
    if (s.zIndex && s.zIndex>9999) {e.style.zIndex=1000}
  }
}
```

I've found you need to call the function at least one second after the page loads, in order for it to work properly. So, I do something like:

```
setTimeout(function(){fixRidiculousZindex()},1000);
```

Good luck!